# FIND_IN_SET() equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid IN (SELECT doctors FROM MainPage WHERE Valid=1)
```

> `users` table `uid INT`
>   
> `Mainpage` table `doctors text` with value as `1,2,3,4,5`

When I am running the above query, it is only resulting 1 row which is for uid = 1, however I wanted all the 5 rows. So in MySQL I used this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
JOIN MainPage ON FIND_IN_SET(uid, doctors)
WHERE Valid = 1;
```

It worked. I am trying to find an equivalent in SQL Server for `FIND_IN_SET` to achieve the same result ?

Comment: In MySQL I assume you have a SET typed column. The closest match to this would be an INT or BIGINT column, used as a flags bitmap.

Comment: Maybe instead you could change your design so you aren't storing multiple facts as single values - in other words you should have a table with DoctorID and UID columns, both ints. Barring doing it the right way, you need a split function. In SQL Server 2016 you can use [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/sql-server-2016/string-split) but prior to that [your options are limited and not very efficient](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might work

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM MainPage
    WHERE CONCAT(',',doctors,',') LIKE CONCAT('%,',u.uid,',%')
        AND Valid = 1
)
```

Comment: I tried it DVT, query only considered 1 from the 1,2,3,4,5. anything else that we can try ?

Comment: My Bad, it works correct. But looks like it will be a performance hit !!!

Comment: i found another way !!

Comment: declare @x varchar(1000) set @x=(select doctors from mainpage where valis=1) exec 'SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE uid in ('+@x+')')

Answer (score 2):

Since SQL Server 2016 (13.x) there is [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE uid IN
 (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(
     (SELECT doctors FROM MainPage WHERE Valid = 1),
     ','))
```

Comment: Looks like entire question is XY Problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36980115/5070879

Comment: @LukaszSzozda, I don't agree. This question is not related to parameterized queries though it looks similar at the first glance. Here is a case when you store comma separated list of ids in database.